# The abstract schema type 'COALESCE' is unknown

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, named-query

I'm using COALESCE in JPA-NamedQuery. I got always this error message on Eclipse:

```
       The abstract schema type 'COALESCE' is unknown.
```

Do you have any idea how to remove it?

Note that the query is working correctly.

**Edit**

The query is

```
@NamedQuery(name = "FootBaller.mostActive", 
    query = "SELECT f FROM FootBaller f ORDER BY COALESCE((SELECT count(*) FROM RelatedMatch rm WHERE rm.footBaller=f), 0) DESC")
```

Comment: How about sharing with people HOW you are using this in "JPA-NamedQuery"? Maybe you're using it wrong?

Comment: It works correctly, but the issue is related with eclipse validation I think.  Here the query:
                  @NamedQuery(name = "FootBaller.mostActive", query = "SELECT f FROM FootBaller f ORDER BY COALESCE((SELECT count(*) FROM RelatedMatch rm WHERE rm.footBaller=f), 0) DESC")

Comment: I rate that as invalid JPQL. Use of COALESCE in the ORDER BY clause is not in any JPQL BNF I've ever seen. You can only order by a "state_field_path_expression | result_variable", and that is none of those. Clearly the message that your JPA provider gives is gibberish, but doesn't hide the fact that it is invalid.

Comment: No comment is possible beyond that since you don't provide your entity class. And please ... PUT THEM IN THE QUESTION NOT IN THE COMMENTS

Answer (score -2):

If you take a look at this; https://dzone.com/articles/the-nasty-jpa-unknown-abstract

Also refer to this, it is more for case sensitivity i.e. user mistakes: [Error on compiling query: The abstract schema type 'entity' is unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20193581/error-on-compiling-query-the-abstract-schema-type-entity-is-unknown)

You may have a lower case somewhere where uppercase is needed, or your annotation is wrong etc.  But refer to the first link above first.